# How do I add two csv files into one graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python, csv, graph

I have two sets of data, both going up the same on the X. both are in CSV files. I would like to input these both onto one graph, but I have gotten stuck.

This is the graph that appears with my current code
[image: This is the graph that appears with my current code].

I need it to reset the X values and have the graphs layer, not go back to `(0,0)` once done.

My tester3 file has data [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtOCn.png)

My tester4 file has data [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjR7D.png)

this is my current code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('tester3.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))
plt.plot(x,y, label='TEST 1!', color='black')
plt.legend()

with open('tester4.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))
plt.plot(x,y, label='TEST 2!', color='green')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can empty `x` and `y` after you plot the first set of plots then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to append the new data to the same x and y arrays, you can do this quick fix:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('tester3.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))
plt.plot(x,y, label='TEST 1!', color='black')
x1=[]
y1=[]
with open('tester4.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x1.append(int(row[0]))
        y1.append(int(row[1]))
plt.plot(x1,y1, label='TEST 2!', color='green')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Using dummy data]

Answer (score 0):

Plot the data separately.  Don't continue adding data to the same collection.

Here's a helper function to load the data into the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

# Note: list(zip(*data)) transposes rows and columns, so x
#       gets the first column numbers and y gets the second.

def plot_data(plt,file,label,color):
    with open(file,newline='') as csvfile:
        x,y = list(zip(*csv.reader(csvfile)))
    plt.plot(x,y,label=label,color=color)

plot_data(plt,'tester3.csv','TEST 1!','black')
plot_data(plt,'tester4.csv','TEST 2!','green')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Two-line graph]